# "The server responded with an error" (HTTP 404) with Google calendar

Tags: mail.app, calendar, ical, google-calendar

I'm using macOS 10.12, a Google account with multiple calendars, and Apple Mail to send/receive email.

When I get invitations from people at work (mostly using Exchange), the emails have an `.ics` file attached. When I open these, Calendar will show this error:

[image]

The error says:

> The URL https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/user@example.com/user encountered HTTP error 404. Make sure the URL is correct.

My calendar settings are basically the default; I just selected a different default calendar. (It's not like Calendar will actually use it to create new events when I double-click `.ics` files, but that's a different issue altogether.)

I've already tried the steps outlined here:

- [Sierra Calendar - Google Calendar: Error 404](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7684941)
- [Server Responded with Error - Mac Calendar](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/phPuCRXiJXc)

… by removing the `com.apple.iCal.plist` setting and the folders `~/Library/Calendars/Calendar Cache`, `~/Library/Calendars/Pending Events` and `~/Library/Calendars/Incoming`. I've also completely removed the Google account from macOS (under *System Preferences » Internet Accounts*) and set it up again.

Manually creating entries works fine, though.

In the Console, I see that this request is sent:

```
[com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.http] [PUT https://user@example.com@apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/user@example.com/events/040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000E05A9DEFFB89D3010000000000000000100000000A23C4C41B14D1498935304A002C0654.ics]
```

Seems pretty normal to me. When I import the same `.ics` file in Google Calendar's Web view, it works fine as well.